# What does "三魂去了两魂半" mean?

Tags: simplified-characters, phrase

It's used to describe an expression so I guess it's close to being shocked or frightened from the context it's used in but I don't really understand why it means that.

So a detailed explanation will be much appreciated.

Comment: 三魂去了两魂半 is too specific. I've never heard it before. It don't think it is a common phrase.

Comment: @TangHo, Maybe it's regional. To me, it's common and it's not something I have to think and understand. It's a common figurative speech though.

Answer (score 5):

The expression is somewhat similar to English *scare the living daylights out of `somebody`*, with many variations. A quick Google search shows

- 三魂[少/去/嚇飛]了二魂
- 三魂剩下半魂
- 三魂去二

and other similar constructions.

三魂 refers to the three [*hun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hun_and_po) in Chinese philosophy/folk religion or Daoist belief. The three *hun* make up a person's "essence" (soul, spirit) when they're alive, and go their separate paths after a person passes away:

- One *hun* returns to the [*primordial universe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wuji_(philosophy)) from whence it came;
- One *hun* faces judgement for the person's good and bad wordly deeds in hell;
- One *hun* resides at a person's burial place or [ancestral tablet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_tablet), and is the *hun* that is passed on to a person's descendants.

If the three *hun* are somehow absent from the body when the body is still alive, then the body becomes a walking corpse (**行尸走肉**), so the expression **三魂去了兩魂半** means *almost frightened to death*.

Answer (score 4):

In order to understand it, you need to know these two phrases: 三魂七魄 and 吓得没了魂儿.

According to Baidu, [三魂七魄](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/12738457.html):

> 人的精神分而可以称之为魂魄，其魂有三，一为天魂，二为地魂，三为命魂。其魄有七，一魄天冲，二魄灵慧，三魄为气，四魄为力，五魄中枢，六魄为精，七魄为英。

So, 三魂 and 七魄 are necessary for a live person. If you lose all 三魂, then you would die.

吓得没了魂儿 means one is **so frightened that he lost his 魂儿(soul) and die**. It's actually a figurative speech. They will not literally lose them and die.

三魂去了两魂半 is a similar phrase to 吓得没了魂儿. You can imagine that “三魂去了两魂半” is about **one loses two and a half of 魂 given he only has three**. Figuratively, it implies that **one almost dies of something frightening or scary**.

So, 吓得没了魂儿 == 吓死了； 三魂去了两魂半 == 吓得半死 or 吓得要死.